# How does the C++ interpret the return value of system()

Tags: c++, linux, bash, system

I need to make my C++ program execute a bash script. So I think I need to use `system()`, here is an example:

bash script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```

C++:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << system("./test.sh") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, I get an `256` etc. Here is what I've found:

```
 test.sh | C++
---------|-----
 exit 0  | 0
 exit 1  | 256
 exit 2  | 512
...
```

I don't know why. Is it possible to get the 0, 1, 2 etc.? Does the value depend on the machine?

Comment: According to **the manual** the return value is (mostly) implementation defined http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @Galik: I assume that he is using Linux where: `The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.,  fork(2)  failed),  and  the return  status  of the command otherwise.` holds. See [Linux manpage of system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

Comment: @AndreKampling however, it is important to mention that return status of a command is not the value returned from `main`.

Comment: have you checked what status does your  shell script produced outside of the c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the value depend on the machine?

Yes (at least as far as C++ standard is concerned).

> it possible to get the 0, 1, 2 etc?

C++ standard does not provide a way to get the return value of the sub-process, but [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html#tag_16_597) does, which applies to you since you use Linux.

> Return Value
>
> If command is a null pointer, system() shall return non-zero to indicate that a command processor is available, or zero if none is available. [CX] [Option Start] The system() function shall always return non-zero when command is NULL. [Option End]
>
> [CX] [Option Start] If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter **in the format specified by waitpid()**. The termination status shall be as defined for the sh utility; otherwise, the termination status is unspecified. If some error prevents the command language interpreter from executing after the child process is created, the return value from system() shall be as if the command language interpreter had terminated using exit(127) or _exit(127). If a child process cannot be created, or if the termination status for the command language interpreter cannot be obtained, system() shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error. [Option End]

[waitpid()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) specifies a macro that can be used to extract the value returned from `main()`.

> WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)
>
> If the value of WIFEXITED(stat_val) is non-zero, this macro evaluates to the low-order 8 bits of the status argument that the child process passed to _exit() or exit(), or the value the child process returned from main().

Comment: So to be clear if you want a portable code you should use a code which depends on the OS (e.g ifdef macro ). If you use windows, you can get the return value directly from system, and if you use linux, you should use POSIX functions WIFEXITED, WEXITSTATUS, WIFSIGNALED, WTERMSIG.
Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments the [return value of `system()` is implementation defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system).
But I assume that you are on Linux where the following holds ([see manpage of `system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system)):

> **Return Value**
>
> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., *fork(2)* failed), and the return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is in the format specified in *wait(2)*. Thus, the exit code of the command will be *WEXITSTATUS(status)*. In case */bin/sh* could not be executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does ***exit***(127).

That means to get the exit status of the command use `WEXITSTATUS()`:

```
std::cout << WEXITSTATUS(system("./test.sh")) << std::endl;
```

The [manpage of `wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) explains `WEXITSTATUS()`, which is defined in the *stdlib.h* header:

> **WEXITSTATUS(status)**
>
> returns the exit status of the child. This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the *status* argument that the child specified in a call to **exit**(3) or **_exit**(2) or as the argument for a return statement in main(). This macro should only be employed if **WIFEXITED** returned true.